# PHP code to split the URL

Tags: php, regex

In the following URL

```
http://www.example.com/usa-florida-1234
```

Can I split the URL with 3 parts in the URL as USA, Florida and 1234??

I just need to do this like a Query String Method for

**Sample Content Like**

My content is posted is `USA` in the city of `florida` and the post code is `1234`

How can I split the URL within `-` dashes

like

```
<?php
$country = // What to keep here?
$city =  // What to keep here?
$code = // What to keep here?
?>
```

My content is posted is `<?php echo $country; ?>` in the city of `<?php echo $city; ?>` and the post code is `<?php echo $code; ?>`

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
list($country, $city, $code) =
    explode('-', ltrim(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH), '/'));
```

No need for a regular expression here.

If the path contains more parts, `country` is going to end up with some undesired path parts.

```
$country = end(explode('/', $country));
```

Comment: I like smart solutions but this one seems to do too much in a single line of code. You can get too verbose though (see my answer).

Comment: All good but I am getting 'test/usa' for country when i try to run as http://localhost/test/usa-florida-1234

Comment: @lock I didn't realize that there were more parts to the path than just the information you needed; this does change the answer a bit.  I'll update it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$arr = parse_url("http://localhost/test/usa-florida-1234");
print_r(explode('-', preg_replace('#^.*?/([^/]+)$#', '$1', $arr['path'])));
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
    [0] => usa
    [1] => florida
    [2] => 1234
)
```

Comment: `Array ( [0] => test/usa [1]` instead of `Array ( [0] => usa [1] `

Comment: when I try to run as http://localhost/test/usa-florida-1234 Array [0] coming as test/USA

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

preg_match('|http://www.example.com/(.*)-(.*)-(.*)|', 'http://www.example.com/usa-florida-1234', $matches);

print_r($matches);


$country = $matches[1];
$city =  $matches[2];
$code = $matches[3];
```

**UPDATE:**

Each character in a regular expression is either understood to be a metacharacter with its special meaning, or a regular character with its literal meaning.

The pattern is composed of a sequence of atoms. The simplest atom is a literal, but grouping parts of the pattern to match an atom will require using ( ) as metacharacters.

When you match a pattern within parentheses, you can use any of $1, $2, ...  or \1 \2 ...(depending on the matcher!) later to refer to the previously matched pattern.

in the example above:

`|` (pipe) - in the example above defines start and the end of the pattern

`()` - both meta-characters `(` and `)` a grouped parts of the pattern

`.` (dot)  = meta-character; matches any single character

`*`  (asterisk) = meta-character, quantifier; defines how often that preceding element(character or group, sub expression) is allowed to occur

Having that in mind:

`(.*)` resolves as a match for later reference a group made of any characters that occur zero or multiple times

And :

`|http://www.example.com/(.*)-(.*)-(.*)|`

Equals to match:

Any occurrence in the text of a string that contains the  string `http://www.example.com/` followed by any character zero or multiple times before the `-` character than again followed by any character zero or multiple times before `-` character followed by any character zero or multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to obtain the path from your URL ('usa-florida-1234').
Then you need to split it by the dash char.

For the first part you can use [parse_url](https://www.php.net/parse_url).
You'll find that it returns a string starting with an '/' also. You'll need to trim it.
Next you can use [explode](https://www.php.net/explode).

```
$urlParts = parse_url('http://www.testdomain.com/usa-florida-1234');
$urlPath = ltrim($urlParts['path'], '/');
$addressParts = explode('-', $urlPath);
$country = $addressParts[0];
$city = $addressParts[1];
$code = $addressParts[2];
```

You should also check that there actually are three strings in the array that `split` returns. Some error checking is always good.

A better solution would be to use an MVC library where you define routes

```
'addressRoute' => '/{country}-{state}-{id}'
```

and handlers for them

```
function addressRoute($country, $state, $id) {
}
```

There are [lots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734741/how-to-build-a-good-router-for-php-mvc) of [discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12430181/how-does-mvc-routing-work) on this [subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033318/is-this-a-good-way-to-match-uri-to-class-method-in-php-for-mvc).

Answer (score 0):

[**`pathinfo`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) and get the basename from the array

```
  <?php
    $var="http://www.testdomain.com/usa-florida-1234";
    $arr=pathinfo($var);
    echo $arr['basename'];
    $arr=explode("-",$arr['basename']);
    print_r($arr);
```

OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
    [0] => usa
    [1] => florida
    [2] => 1234
)
```

Answer (score -1):

If all of the URLs used are to be expected in that format, you could use an explode() there.

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/usa-florida-1234";
$parts = explode('-', $url);
$country = $parts[0];
$city = $parts[1];
$code = $parts[2];
```